# Integral of $\sinh^2(x)$ using t-substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

So I have this integral:

$$I = \int \frac{\gamma^4v^2}{\pi\sinh^2(\sqrt{2}\gamma v/\sqrt{h})}dh $$

I used a $t$-substitution but only got as far as:

$$t = \frac{\sqrt{2}\gamma v}{\sqrt{h}} \Rightarrow da = \frac{-\sqrt{2}h^{3/2}}{\gamma v}$$

When the  stated solution is

$$\int \frac{dt}{t^2\sinh^2{t}}$$

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to work the other way

Let
$$\frac{\sqrt{2} \gamma  v}{\sqrt{h}}=t \implies h=\frac{2 \gamma ^2 v^2}{t^2}\implies dh=-\frac{4 \gamma ^2 v^2}{t^3}\,dt$$ this makes the integral to be
$$-\frac{4 \gamma ^6 v^4}\pi \int\frac{\text{csch}^2(t)}{  t^3}\,dt$$

Probably typo's.